# How to change a name of one field in large Json using Jolt

Tags: jolt

I have a big Json document:

```
{ "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3",
...
 "field1000": "value1000"
}
```

I want to change the name of one field (field3) to third_field

How to do it without writing specification like that:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
       "field1": "field1",
       "field2": "field2",
       "field3": "third_field",
       ...
       "field1000": "field1000"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work and essentially does an `if then else`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      //if
      "field3": {
        //$ - current value
        "$": "third_field"
      },
      //else
      "*": {
        //$ - current value
        //& - current key
        "$": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```